# PHP connect to mySQL issue with script logic?

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone experienced tell me why this does not work, while it should by conventions and practices in php and SQL.

```
$con = mysql_connect($conf['host'],$conf['user'],$conf['pass']) or die ("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db($conf['database'])or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$g_Username'");

if (!$sql) 
{
    die("query failed: " . msql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, MYSQL_ASSOC ))
{

    $salt = $row['salt'];
    $md5_pass = MD5(md5($g_Password) . $salt);

    if( $g_Username == $row['username']  && $md5_pass == $row['password'] )
    {
        print("g_userOk ");
        addLog("$g_Username Authenticated");
    }
}

mysql_close();
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are the variables correct? What type of error are you getting?

Comment: Don't use the mysql_* functions, they're deprecated and don't work properly with modern versions of MySQL.  Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Comment: Where the issue occurs ? Excerpt of your error (with line involved) ? Using mysql functions is needed or not ? (this last point means if you can, switch to `MySqli` or `PDO` like @GordonM said).

Comment: @GordonM my sql version is: MySQL Version 5.5.40. Can you recommend what should I use then? Where can I find the guides on converting to new system like mysqli or pdo.

Also I do not get any error, it just doesn't work.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php for MYSQLI and http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php for PDO, both are equals, PDO is for my mind the best while using prepared statements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

mysql is deprecated.
use pdo or mysqli instead.

nevertheless ... you have a typo error:

change

```
die("query failed: " . msql_error());
```

to

```
die("query failed: " . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you, with that and few other suggestions we managed to fix it.